# Magento 2 : Add to Cart Button redirect to contact page

Tags: magento2, redirect-url

I am using Magento 2, How to redirect to contact us page when adding a product to add to cart?

Answer (score 1):

In that case you need to create a plugin for it.

**Vendor/ModuleName/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add">
        <plugin name="redirect_contact_add_to_cart" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Vendor/ModuleName/Plugin/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php**

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Checkout\Controller\Cart;

class Add
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory
     */
    protected $resultRedirectFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $url;

    /**
     * Data constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    ) {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        $contactUrl = $this->url->getUrl('contact');
        $result = [];
        $result['backUrl'] = $contactUrl;

        $subject->getResponse()->representJson(
            $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')->jsonEncode($result)
        );
        return;
    }
}
```