# Magento 2: How to complete AJAX request in Plugin?

Tags: magento2, plugin, magento-2.1.4

[Magento 2 : Add to Cart Button redirect to contact page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121597/magento-2-add-to-cart-button-redirect-to-contact-page)

I have the below code which works fine. But it's not completing the AJAX request.

```
namespace Custom\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Controller\Cart;

class Add {

    protected $_checkoutSession;
    protected $_messageManager;
    protected $_redirect;
    protected $_request;
    protected $_response;


    public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession, \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect, \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager, \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request, \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response) {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_redirect = $redirect;
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_response = $response;

    }

    public function beforeExecute(\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add $subject) { // Before Product Added to Cart
        $this->_messageManager->addError(__('Error'));
        $this->_request->setParam('product', false); // Will not add product to Cart
        $this->_response->setRedirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        $this->_checkoutSession->setNoCartRedirect(false);
    }
}
```

It keeps showing "Adding.." on the "Add to Cart" button.

Comment: what you want? redirect or calling only?

Comment: Hi @SohelRana I would like to complete my AJAX request

Comment: At the end when i put `echo 1;  exit;` it completes the AJAX request

Answer (score 1):

Drop the redirect line:

```
 $this->_response->setRedirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
```

That one should be there only if you are not in an ajax call.

So you can have something like this:

```
if ($this->_request->isAjax()) {
    $this->_response->setRedirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
}
```

but since this is a `before` plugin that does not return anything, the original method will be called and the redirection will be handled in the original method.

And a side note...I don't think you need that many dependencies. Unless you have other logic in your class that needs those dependencies.

Comment: It's still not working. I also tried to put ur code in `afterExecute` method. Still it's showing "Adding..."

Comment: At the end when i put `echo 1;  exit;` it completes the AJAX request

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Custom\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Controller\Cart;

class Add {

    protected $_checkoutSession;
    protected $_messageManager;
    protected $_redirect;
    protected $_request;
    protected $_response;
    protected $_jsonHelperData;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession, \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect, \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager, \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request, \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response, \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelperData) {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_redirect = $redirect;
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_response = $response;
        $this->_jsonHelperData = $jsonHelperData;
    }

    public function beforeExecute(\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add $subject) { // Before Product Added to Cart
        $this->_messageManager->addError(__('Error'));
        $this->_request->setParam('product', false); // Will not add product to Cart
        $this->_response->setRedirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        $this->_checkoutSession->setNoCartRedirect(false);
        $subject->getResponse()->representJson($this->_jsonHelperData->jsonEncode(['success' => true])); // Need to Add this LINE
    }
}
```

Below line need to add

```
$subject->getResponse()->representJson($this->_jsonHelperData->jsonEncode(['success' => true])); // Need to Add this LINE
```